# how can I get the current date minus 20 seconds in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, date, get

how can I get the current date minus 20 seconds in javascript?
I can not figure out how to subtract 20 seconds to the current date in javascript
how can I do, I get a negative value in this way

There is an easier way?
thanks

```
var currentDate = new Date()
var day = currentDate.getDate()
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
var ora = currentDate.getHours()
var minuti = currentDate.getMinutes()
var secondi = currentDate.getSeconds()-20
```

Comment: `new Date(new Date - 20000)`

Answer (score 55):

Give this a shot:

```
new Date(Date.now() - 20000);
```

The `Date.now()` returns the milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00, so we just subtract 20000 milliseconds from that, and use the result to create a new date.

As @rjz noted, you'll need a shim for old IE. The MDN shim is below:

```
if (!Date.now) {
     Date.now = function() { return new Date().getTime(); }
}
```

Comment: Worth considering a polyfill (or alternative to `Date.now`) If you're planning to use this in IE<9 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

Comment: Doesn't `new Date().valueOf()` return the current time in milliseconds as well? That should eliminate the need for a polyfill.

Comment: @GJK: Yes, but then we could just use `.getTime()` directly as well. The shorter `Date.now()` is nice, but you're right, not strictly necessary.

Comment: @GJK Exactly. Simply `new Date(new Date - 20000)` would work just fine.

Comment: @AaditMShah: Ah yeah, I see I missed the point. That would be a good way too.

Comment: If you are planning to use IE < 9 you should consider quit your job or tear up your diploma.

Answer (score 4):

I would do it something like this:

```
function DateOffset( offset ) {
    return new Date( +new Date + offset );
}

var twentySecondsAgo = DateOffset( -20000 );

// Should differ by 20 seconds (modulo 60)
alert(
    twentySecondsAgo.getSeconds() +
    '\n' +
    new Date().getSeconds()
);
```

With this code you don't need any shims or polyfills or any of that stuff. I just tested it in IE 5.5 and Netscape 4.79 and it works fine there! That's why I used `alert()` in the test instead of `console.log()`, so I could test it in those old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the - 20 that appears after getSeconds()

and then add this a line below it or more

```
secondi = secondi - 20;
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything. `secondi` ends up with exactly the same value.